# unable to access folder just created Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script that generates a folder in Google Drive and gets the folder ID of that folder.

Upon trying to access that folder in a unique function I get the error:

no item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it on Folder

Please see my script below (called independently from html):

```
var childFolderIdA;


function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('multifile').setTitle('test –     multi upload').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function test(parent,child){
   createSharedSubFolder(parent,child);
}

function createSharedSubFolder(parent,child) { // folder names as string parameters 
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var exist = false
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  if(folder.getName()==parent){exist = true ; var folderId = folder.getId();  break};// find the existing parent folder
  }
  if(exist){ //parent folder exists
    var child = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(child).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    var childFolderId = child.getId();
    childFolderIdA = childFolderId;
    }else{
    var childFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(parent).createFolder(child);            //create parent and child folders
    childFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    } 
}

function saveFile(data,name,folderName) { 
  var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';'));

  var file = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)), contentType, name); //does the uploading of the files
  DriveApp.getFolderById(childFolderIdA).createFile(file);
}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't depend on global variables to save state between calls. Each time you call a script a new script instance is spawned. Each one will maintain its own state.

For example:

```
google.script.run.createSharedSubFolder(...) --> Script Instance 1..var childFolderIdA=folderId;

google.script.run.saveFile(...) --> Script Instance 2..var childFolderIdA=null;
```

You can save the the folderId to the users property store:

```
PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("childFolderId", childFolderId);
```

You can retrieve the folder Id:

```
var folderId = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("childFolderId");
```

Your code with this change:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('multifile').setTitle('test –     multi upload').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function test(parent,child){
   createSharedSubFolder(parent,child);
}

function createSharedSubFolder(parent,child) { // folder names as string parameters 
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var exist = false
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  if(folder.getName()==parent){exist = true ; var folderId = folder.getId();  break};// find the existing parent folder
  }
  if(exist){ //parent folder exists
    var child = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFolder(child).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    var childFolderId = child.getId();
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("childFolderId", childFolderId);

    }else{
    var childFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(parent).createFolder(child);            //create parent and child folders
    childFolder.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
    } 
}

function saveFile(data,name,folderName) { 
  var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';'));

  var file = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)), contentType, name); //does the uploading of the files
  var childFolderId = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("childFolderId");
  DriveApp.getFolderById(childFolderId).createFile(file);
}
```

Comment: @specer-easton Thanks for the tip. I'm going to try it and let you know!

Comment: @specer-easton I appreciate your suggestion. There must be something I don't understand about how the PropertiesService works as it generally seems to keep the data for a previous folder instead of the last one created. Have any additional tips?

Comment: @arsc I added how I would change your code  with the propertyservice. Does that match how your made your changes?

Comment: @specer-easton, Thank you again for your help.

I must have made some other error, because upon running the it, I get an error Invalid argument, but when I write the file to the parent directory, it works.  What's even stranger is the Logger does not show the function running, but I tested it by commenting out only the last time and no errors are generated, but still not Logger?!?!

Comment: resolved the error, but still can't get the Logger to show for the saveFile function and it's not working. I created another version without folder creation. With that I successfully wrote and read the ServicesProperties, but still not working for this. 

Any tips in general on what it means if the Logger is not showing for the function in question?

Comment: @arsc Logger works the same way as global variables. It will only save to that specific instance of the script.

Comment: @specer-easton Thank you got it working!!!

I put in a 3 second timeout in the javascript before creating the files, to give Google time to get the folder created, but once I did that, it works!

If I didn't do that then short lists of files will not work, as Google did not recognize the folderId.